# Sed Grab everything before a comma

Tags: csv, sed, grep

I have a csv file with the following headers and content:

```
Country,Fertility,Income
"United States","23,2","1222,21"
```

I am looking to grab everything before the comma in the Income column. So that I have the following output

```
Country,Fertility,Income
"United States","23,2","1222"
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried sed like so sed sed -e 's/^[^,]+"//g' < MortalityFertilityIncome.csv >new.tsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/,[0-9]*"$/"/' file
```

Output:

```
Country,Fertility,Income
"United States","23,2","1222"
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)